# Define type as a contravariant parent of another type

Tags: typescript

Consider type `Foo` as:

```js
type Foo = {
  name: string,
  bar: {
    buzz: string,
    buzzy: number,
    buzzAldrin: boolean
  },
  active: boolean,
}
```

I want to define a type which represents a "part" of `Foo`. For example:

- `{name: string}`
- `{name: string, active: boolean}`
- `{bar: { buzz: string } }`

Another way to see it is, a type that's `Foo`'s parent type when viewed as a contravariant parameter. So, naming that type `CFoo`, it would satisfy:

```
((arg: CFoo) => any) extends ((arg: Foo) => any)
```

I can represent that relationship with a type that takes both `Foo` and `CFoo` and performs the assertion above:

```js
type Contra<T, G> = ((a: G) => void) extends ((a: T) => void) ? G : never;

type Foo = {
    shape: string,
    name: 'circle',
    b: {
        d: string
    }
}

function test<T, G>(a: T, b: G extends Contra<T, G> ? G : never) {};

let a = {} as Foo;

test(a, {b: {d: 'asd'}}); // No error
test(a, {shape: 'test'}) // No error
test(a, {shape: 123}) // Error
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=18&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gO2AJwIYB4AqAaKBxAPigF4oAKM1ALnwEoSiA3OASwBN6IAPYCBNgM7lKNTPWJNWHKAH58UGggiMIyANwAoDaEhQAYnDgkoAbw1QLUAQAtUkGgJQsEAc2znLCVAFsINAOQAxizIgQA2EP7ullAARjRmMTFsDk6uHhYAvhrZGgBmAK4IgcAsiFC8jli4hCJQOHE0eFDcvPxC8Eho1fhEcs2Kyqr0JpmaGhHAUKjGo9NCBnDjlcCUuCbxpilQ-qgCbP6ZmbRqUAD0Z1AAckaqyHDI2hCOa6Y2dn47K4f0F9e3yHujxWrxM73sUAAjAAmADMx3OlwAooCHloNEA)

But, what I really want to do is define a generic type that, when passed `Foo` produces a general contravariant parent type that I can use more succinctly.

```js
type Contra<T> = // type definition
function test<T>(a: T, b: Contra<T>) {} // Should accept parameters just like the example above.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you over-engineered it:

```js
function test<T, G extends T extends G ? unknown : T>(a: T, b: G) {};
```

You are also allowed to return something other than `never`. You get a nicer error message by returning `T`, and is not going to make the type invariant because it's only evaluated when the first comparison fails.

Now, this is also an option:

```js
function test<T extends G, G>(a: T, b: G) {};
```

Of course the error does not pop up in the same spot, but it does not always matter.

Comment: This is excellent! Works perfectly especially with type hinting, error messages, and intellisense. I see that you flipped how the relation is asserted. `T` to `G` instead of the other way around. Can you explain why this gives such good error messages and why you're returning `unknown`?

Comment: Also could we then define a standalone generic type that emualtes this `ParentOf<T>` relationship? So be able to use it outside of function definitions (but still with one generic input type)

Comment: You can think of this conditional type as a way to dynamically produce a simple, flat, type definition. This type definition can either be `unknown` or `T`. `unknown` is transparent, so it's going to accept any `G`, but that's OK because we only return `unknown` when `T extends G`. The check kind of happens in 2 steps. Another way to think of it is as the opposite of returning `never` in a conditional type: it all depends what branch interests you the most. `never` is the neutral element of union while `unknown` is the neutral element of interesection.

Comment: By returning `T` when `T extends G` fails, we simply replace a contravariant check by a covariant check. You would not want a covariant check to happen unconditionally, but since it is disabled when `T extend G` you don't get the downsides of doing it.

Comment: You can define this utility type `Contra<T, G> = T extends G ? unknown : T`, which was simply inlined in my answer, but I don't think it adds a lot of value because when reading `test<T, G extends Contra<T, G>>` you can't really tell in which order T and G will be compared. It can make sense to do it when you compare deep properties of `T` and `G`. This is what I do in the library free-types which re-implements poor-man type constraints in higher kinded types

Comment: Thank you for the explanations! A lot of it is clicking for me thanks to these comments. Would it be possible to define a utility type that wouldn't need `G`? It would need to reference itself and compare to `T` somehow. Essentially generalizing `G`. `type G = ParentOf<T>`.

Comment: No, the only way to have `G` relate to `T` is by mentioning both. By the way, if TS yells because a generic circularly references itself in a type constraint, which can happen if you do this kind of dynamic check, you can use an indirection to defuse it, like so: `<T extends Check, Check = Something<T>>`.